# Mongodb PHP driver : MongoCursorException

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I had decided to upgrade mongo in version 2.4.0.
I use the php driver in his last version, but now when I do a batchInsert() sometime i have this error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'Couldn't get 
>   connection: Failed to connect (my mongos URL) package: error reading from socket: cursor 
>   timed out (timeout: 10000, time left: 0:0, status: 0)

Can someone explain me what this error is and how can i resolve my problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is some kind of connection problem between the PHP app and MongoDB, check your firewall etc to see if something is being blocked

Comment: i don't think there is a problem with something which block my query or something like that because that work but sometimes the timeout append.
Is there anyway to change the mongodb cursor timeout ?

Comment: There is: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php , however, does this happen for a certain query consistently cos if it does it could denote a slow query then, if it is random you could be having a intermedant network problem.

Comment: i allready set the MongoCursor::$timeout = -1  but the problem coming from elsewhere .. there is a problem with a socket timeout there is only 1 second for the socket to answer but if there any kind of lag on the network i my query will never going back to me so i'm screw

Comment: Hmm, what setup do you have? Do you use Apache?

Comment: I use apache with the last driver
i'm in development so i have 1 mongod 1 mongos and 3 shards

Comment: Setting the static MongCursor::$timeout property isn't particularly encouraged as it will be deprecated in the future (although it should currently work - You will however need to set it before you construct the cursor object.

Try doing ..->batchInsert(..., array("timeout" => your-timeout)) and see if that solves your problem.